# Kusto - If else condition with Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I am trying to convert the below Splunk query to Kusto.

`| eval result=if(Match(Status,"Success|Passed"), "succeess","failed")`

Below is the example  from Kusto that is not clear . How do I modify this Kusto example as per the above Splunk Query pls. Thanks
`| extend day = iff(floor(Timestamp, 1d)==floor(now(), 1d), "today", "anotherday")`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
... 
| summarize success = countif(Status in ("Success", "Passed")), total = count() 
| project success, failure = total - success
```

- in case the values in the column named `Status` can have different casing, you can use `in~()`
- in case the values in the column named `Status` are longer strings, which you want to look for substring in, you can use, for example: `Status contains "Success" or Status contains "Passed"`

Comment: Thanks the query works but both the results appear in the same column . Is there a way to display the Success and failure count  in 2 diff columns against the JobId. Please see my original question for how the table results looks like.

Comment: Please see the updated answer, assuming I understood your intention correctly

Comment: I was able to complete the Query . Thanks.

```| summarize succeeded = countif(Status=="Success" or Status=="Passed"),
            failure = countif(Status!="Success" or Status!="Passed")```

Comment: i think your second condition should use `and` instead of `or`

Comment: Below is the Splunk query. Does it mean (Sucsess or passed) or (Success and passed) in Kusto 

```| eval result=if(Match(Status,"Success|Passed")```

Comment: It means `or`. I was referring to the fact that in your previous comment you used "status isn't success or status isn't passed" instead of "status isn't success and status isn't passed"